# Setting the type to the incoming apiye state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api

I want to put an incoming API to the status but it says undefined.
I want to discard my data coming to randomcocktail and then use it.

Random.tsx

```
    import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { CocktailType } from "../Utils/data";
import "../Style/index.scss";

    const Random = () => {
  const [randomCocktail, setRandomCocktail] = useState<CocktailType[]>();



useEffect(() => {
    const getRand = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php"
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      const { cocktail = [] } = data;

      setRandomCocktail(cocktail[0]);
      console.log(data);
      console.log(randomCocktail);
    };
    getRand();
  }, []);



 return (
    <div className="randomPage">
      <div className="leftRand"></div>
      <div className="rightRand"></div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Random;
```

data.ts

```
export type CocktailType={
strDrink :string;
strTag:string|null;
strVideo:string|null;
strCategory:string;
strIBA:string|null;
strAlcoholic:string;
strGlass:string;
strInstructions:string;
strDrinkThumb:string;
```

}

api : https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php

Comment: Can you elaborate on the actual issue? Are you getting any error in particular?

Comment: The api response does not seem to have `cocktail` field. That might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { CocktailType } from "../Utils/data";
import "../Style/index.scss";

    const Random = () => {
  const [randomCocktail, setRandomCocktail] = useState<CocktailType[]>();



useEffect(() => {
    const getRand = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php"
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      const cocktail = data.drinks;

      setRandomCocktail(cocktail[0]);
      console.log(data);
      console.log(randomCocktail);
    };
    getRand();
  }, []);



 return (
    <div className="randomPage">
      <div className="leftRand"></div>
      <div className="rightRand"></div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Random;
```